# Karate framework: On running gatling test, can we configure to get the cucumber report aswell

Tags: karate

In gatling report i don't get to see the failed scenarios. So can we also have cucumber report when we run the gatling test so that the failed steps can be known.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will add un-necessary overhead to the test-execution - so this is not (and perhaps will never be) supported by Karate.

Do note that the failures (and line number) will appear in the Gatling report: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/986463717465391104

Comment: The failures gives the line number in gatling report, but can we print the response value in the report all each run. Like for example i want to print the order numbers which i get in the response to debug the failures.

Comment: @sam no - responses can be huge. there can be binary files. note that this is open-source. contribute code or look for another solution, thanks